# Алгоритм "пузырьковой" сортировки

Tags: c#, алгоритм, сортировка, пузырьковая-сортировка

Это моя попытка реализации, сортировки "пузырьком". Я только учусь программированию, потому не судите строго. Подскажите почему код не работает, и правилен ли ход мыслей?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CSharp_Shell
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int [] ms = new int[10] { 4, 6, 2, 5, 7, 47, 3, 8, 11, 34 };

            foreach (int k in ms)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(k);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("~");

            int num = 0;
            int temp;
            int ccl = 0;
            while(ccl < 5)
            {
               for (int len = ms.Length - 1; len > 0; len--)
               {
                   if (ms[num] < ms[num+1])
                   {
                       temp = ms[num];
                       ms[num] = ms[num+1];
                       ms[num+1] = temp;
                   }
                   num++;
               }

               ccl++;
            }

            foreach (int k in ms)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

При сортировке пузырьком у вас должно быть 2 цикла : внешний и внутренний.

Внешний цикл идёт до конца вашего массива, внутренний до `ms.Length - i - 1`.

```
int[] ms = new int[10]
{
    4,6,2,5,7,47,3,8,11,34
};

foreach (int k in ms)
{
    Console.Write(k + " ");
}
Console.WriteLine();

int temp = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < ms.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ms.Length - i - 1; j++)
    {
        if (ms[j] > ms[j+1])
        {
            temp = ms[j];
            ms[j ] = ms[j + 1];
            ms[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

foreach (int k in ms)
{
    Console.Write(k + " ");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Это другой алгоритм: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сортировка_выбором

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код не всегда приводит к желаемому результату, так как в нём предполагается,
что массив из десяти элементов `new int[10]` будет гарантированно отсортирован **сортировкой пузырьком** за пять проходов (`ccl < 5`).

**Это не так**: в худшем случае минимальный элемент будет лежать в самом конце массива, и каждый проход массива пузырьковым методом будет спускать него только на одну позицию.

Соответственно для сортировки массива из десяти элементов может потребоваться до девяти проходов массива. Нужно заменить проверку `ccl < 5` на `ccl < 9` (где `9` это `ms.Length - 1`).

Это самая грубая реализация этого алгоритма сортировки, но при этом и самая простая.

Помимо этого у вас есть ошибки в алгоритме прохода массива из конца в начало.
Минимальные необходимые исправления выглядят следующим образом:

```
using System;

namespace CSharp_Shell
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            int[] ms = new int[10] { 4, 6, 2, 5, 7, 47, 3, 8, 11, 34 };

            foreach (int k in ms)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(k);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("~");

            int temp;
            int ccl = 0;
            while (ccl < 9)
            {
                for (int len = ms.Length - 2; len > -1; len--)
                {
                    if (ms[len] < ms[len + 1])
                    {
                        temp = ms[len];
                        ms[len] = ms[len + 1];
                        ms[len + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
                ccl++;
            }

            foreach (int k in ms)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

См. также [Сортировка пузырьком — Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC).